# Lodash returns wrong reduce result if there is only one object in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I get an array of objects with some values which I need to sum. Sometimes there is only one item in the array.
In that case I get a wrong value.

```
var sumGood = _.reduce([{value:1},{value:2}], function(sum, n) { 
    return sum.value + n.value; });
console.log(sumGood)
//  3

var sumBad = _.reduce([{value:1}], function(sum, n) { 
    return sum.value + n.value; });
console.log(sumBad)
// Object {value: 1}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59v398mb/)

How to make it return the proper result which is 3 and 1 respectively?

Comment: How is the last one 3?

Comment: My bad, in the last case it surely should be one, but not an object.

Comment: O horror, it doesn't return *any result at all* for arrays with zero or three elements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preffered solution:** You can set the third parameter of reduce as the initial iteration, here {value: 0}. Without that, lodash cannot know what the previous `sum` is if you have only one item.

```
_.reduce(array, function(sum, n) {
    return sum.value + n.value;
}, {value:0});
```

Alternatvely you could add a 0 value to your array before the reduce:

```
array.unshift( {value: 0} ) // now array is [{value:0}, {value:1}}]
```

Or do a map-reduce:

```
_(array).pluck('value').reduce(function(sum, n) { return sum + n; })
```

Or why not check your array's size before?

```
if (array.length === 1) { return array[0].value; } else { ...reduce... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an initial accumulator `_.reduce(collection, [iteratee=_.identity], [accumulator], [thisArg])`

```js
var sum3 = _.reduce([{
    value: 1
  }, {
    value: 2
  }, {
    value: 3
  }],
  function(memo, num) {
    return memo + num.value;
  },
  0
);

console.log(sum3);

var sum1 = _.reduce([{
    value: 1
  }],
  function(memo, num) {
    return memo + num.value;
  },
  0
);

console.log(sum1);


var otherWay = _.reduce([{
  value: 1
}, {
  value: 2
}, {
  value: 3
}], function(memo, num) {
  memo.value = memo.value + num.value;
  return memo;
}, {
  value: 0
}).value;

console.log(otherWay)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works for a single item in the array, but return NaN for multiple items. http://jsfiddle.net/59v398mb/3/